# free(): double free detected in tcache 2, in linked List deletion of a node in c++ and how destructor is working in this code

Tags: c++, oop, destructor, singly-linked-list

```
class Node{
    public:
        int data;
        Node* next;
        
        Node(int d){
            data = d;
            next = NULL;
        }
        
        ~Node(){
            delete next;
        }
};
```

```
class List{
    public:
        Node* head;
        Node* tail;
        
        List(){
            head = NULL;
            tail = NULL;
        }
        
        ~List(){
            delete head;
        }
        
        void push_back(int data){
            Node* n = new Node(data);
            if(head == NULL){
                head = tail = n;
            }else{
                tail->next = n;
                tail = n;
            }
        }
        void print(){
            Node* temp = head;
            while(temp != NULL){
                cout<<temp->data<<" ";
                temp = temp->next;
            }
        }
        void deleteNode(int d){
            Node* curr = head;
            Node* prev = NULL;
            while(curr != NULL){
                if(curr->data == d){
                    if(prev == NULL){
                        head = head->next;
                        delete curr;
                        break;
                    }else{
                        prev->next = curr->next;
                        curr->next = NULL;
                        delete curr;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                prev = curr;
                curr = curr->next;
            }
        }
};
```

```
int main(){
    List l;
    l.push_back(1);
    l.push_back(2);
    l.push_back(3);
    l.push_back(4);
    l.push_back(5);
    l.deleteNode(1);
    l.print();
}
```

If I delete 1 from 1->2->3->4->5

**Expected Output**: 2->3->4->5

**Output**: free(): double free detected in tcache 2;

**Reason**: Destructor in Node Class. If I remove it is working fine.

**Doubt** : If I **remove destructor** in Node class in Node class **then how can I free up memory**. And can anyone also explain **how destructors are working in both Node and List class**.

**Can someone please help me with this, or can provide alternative solution.**

**Thank You!!!**

Comment: Why, just why are people coming to C++, then *ignore* most of C++ just to reimplement basic data containers (a.k.a. "the wheel") using practices mostly inherited from C? You want a linked list, [`#include <forward_list>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list). And no, reimplementing it like shown here is not "good practice", it's "practicing all the things you shouldn't have to do anymore in the first place, ever".

Comment: @DevSolar Brother I am newbie, and I am learning it. Could you please provide an article related to good practice for implementing it. Thanks!!!!

Comment: The point I am trying to make is that *the whole point of the C++ standard library is that you do not have to implement basic data structures yourself*. Like, ever. Practice using the standard library instead of practicing building data structures. *It has been done for you.* You don't need this particular skill. Knowing how to look up and *using* standard functionality is what makes you a good C++ coder. Not throwing pointers to allocated memory around. This is C++, not C.

Comment: By extension, if you find yourself in a course / tutorial that tells you how to do stuff like that (manual memory handling, naked pointers, C-style arrays, ...), just drop it and find a better course / tutorial. They are hard to find, because unfortunately most instructors have not yet taken it to heart that we should [stop teaching C](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`~Node(){ delete next; }` makes it hard to delete a single node from that list. It'll delete *all* nodes after it too.

I suggest that the individual `Node`s do not `delete` following `Node`s:

```c++
class Node {
public:
    int data;
    Node* next;

    Node(int d) : // colon starts the member initializer list
        data(d), next(nullptr)
    {
        // the body of the constructor can now be empty
    }

    // No user-defined destructor needed here
};
```

Instead, `delete` all `Node`s in the destructor of `List`:

```c++
    ~List() {
        for(Node* next; head; head = next) {
            next = head->next;
            delete head; 
        }
    }
```

---

Unrelated to the problem at hand. These are just suggestions:

You could make the constructor of `Node` a little more versatile so it's possible to provide the next `Node` already at construction:

```c++
class Node {
public:
    int data;
    Node* next;

    // `nullptr` below is a default argument that will be used if the
    // user of this class does not provide a second argument
    Node(int d, Node* n = nullptr) :
        data(d), next(n)
    {}
};
```

This could be used in a `List` member function called `push_front`:

```c++
    void push_front(int data) {
        head = new Node(data, head);
        if(!tail) tail = head;
    }
```

Unrelated to that, you *could* make `push_back` a little clearer without even changing the current `Node` at all:

```c++
    void push_back(int data) {
        Node* n = new Node(data);

        if(tail)  tail->next = n;
        else      head = n;

        tail = n;
    }
```

Comment: Brother how are you able to write constructor like this, could you send me an article on best practices to write constructor and destructor. Thanks!!!

Comment: @YAbhishakeKumar I added some explanations to the constructors I added.

Answer (score 0):

To follow up on my comments: Throw away both your `Node` and `List` class, and actually use the language:

```
#include <forward_list>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::forward_list< int > l { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    l.remove( 1 );
    for ( auto & node : l )
    {
        std::cout << node << " ";
    }
}
```